# How do I average the success metric of each word in message for over a hundred messages

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, flatten, google-query-language

I'm hoping to use google sheets to determine the profitability of each word in around 100 10-25 word messages.

Right now I'm starting with something along the lines of this:

| Message | Success | Word Count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Cats are gross | 150% | 3 |
| I love Dogs | 250% | 3 |
| I love Dogs and Cats are gross | 450% | 6 |

To query the word usage I'm using the formula:

`=ArrayFormula(query(Flatten(split(trim(REGEXREPLACE(LOWER(Message1:Message), "[!?,.:;-]"," "))," ")), "SELECT Col1, COUNT(Col1) Group By Col1",0))`

This gets me to here:

| Word | Count |
| --- | --- |
| cats | 2 |
| are | 2 |
| gross | 2 |
| i | 2 |
| love | 2 |
| dogs | 2 |
| and | 1 |

And I'm using this formula to assign the Success% to each word using the word count as its basis for splitting the words and copying down:

`=IFERROR(IF(COUNTIF(Value$1:Value2,Value2)<=VLOOKUP(Value2,$Success$2:$Word_Count$100,6,FALSE),Value2,IF(OFFSET($Success$2,MATCH(Value2,$Success$2:$Success$100,0),0)="","",OFFSET($Success$2,MATCH(Value2,$Success$2:$Success$100,0),0))),"")`

This gets me here:

| Word | Value |
| --- | --- |
| cats | 150% |
| are | 150% |
| gross | 150% |
| I | 250% |
| love | 250% |
| dogs | 250% |
| I | 450% |
| love | 450% |
| dogs | 450% |
| and | 450% |
| cats | 450% |
| are | 450% |
| gross | 450% |

What formula could I use to combine these data sets to get me to here:

| Word | Count | Success AVG |
| --- | --- | --- |
| cats | 2 | 300% |
| are | 2 | 300% |
| gross | 2 | 300% |
| I | 2 | 350% |
| love | 2 | 350% |
| dogs | 2 | 350% |
| and | 1 | 450% |

Comment: Well, which? make a decision .

Comment: I'd say Sheets, apologies

Comment: can you share a copy/sample of your sheets?

Comment: @player0 I can absolutely do that. Give me a little bit here to edit for the internet

Comment: @player0 https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1KWJE-iTOyKOFOK2XauwtAG2BHZOR9AvImcyjbGCXYIs/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(LOWER(A2:A), 
 "[!?,.:;-]", " "), " ")&"×"&B2:B), "×"), 
 "select Col1,count(Col1),avg(Col2)
  where Col2 is not null 
  group by Col1 
  label Col1'Word',count(Col1)'Count',avg(Col2)'Success AVG'"))
```

[image]

---

[image]

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thank you @player0 ! If I could ask one thing, how would I go about adding a second success value and it calculating in another column with all the same attributes? If not thank you so much for this it was incredibly helpful!

Comment: @AllAPartOfThePlan https://i.stack.imgur.com/n72JP.png